# Can I make active_tasks not require authentication

Tags: couchdb

The CouchDB URL /_active_tasks is great for providing information about progress on replication and indexing. But in order to view it, you must be logged in as an admin. In my couchapp I want to be able to show my user the progress of indexing/replication, but I don't want them to be logged in as administrators. Is there a setting somewhere to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible, because `/_active_tasks` may potentially reveal information that you don't want to get leaked out like remote peers which may be your end users. If you need to track status of user replication you need to use [_replicator](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/replication/replicator.html) database. But it'll provide only basic information about it like is it dead or in progress or completed. If you feel that this isn't fair, feel free to [file an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB) or even send us [pull request](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/pulls) (:

Answer (score 0):

One hack would be to create a simple sinatra (or whatever) service that just runs a curl request as admin against _active_tasks and reposts the result.